# div with a background image inside - scale to browser

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to scale background images within a common div (framework) to resize with the browser. Not sure if the only way to do this is with Javascript I have looked around but nothing seems to have my case. I would appreciate any help.

Link to the live site page that I am trying to fix http://ryankelly.info/work.html

HTML

```
 <div id="workcontent">
    <div class="work">

        <div class="subnav"></div>

        <a href="ggwp.html">
        <div class="framework" style="height: 1085px; transform: translateZ(0px)        translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
        <div class="ggwp-img"></div>
        <div class="workblock"></div>
        <div class="workblock-text"><h1>GGWP</h1></div>

        <div class="workblocktwo"></div>

        </div>
        </a>
```

CSS

```
 .work {
     background: #141414 none repeat scroll 0 0;
     margin: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     text-align:left;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow:auto;
     overflow-y:hidden;
     border: 1px  solid;
     background: #141414 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  }
  .framework {
     height: 20px;
     width: 400px;
     border: 1px red solid;
     display: inline-block; 
  }
   .ggwp-img {
     background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34); 
     background-image: url('images/ggwp.jpg'); 
     background-size: cover; opacity:0.25;
     position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast simple way to do it using css.

```
.ggwp-img {
    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34); 
    background-image: url('images/ggwp.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover; opacity:0.25;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Comment: This would work if my image was inline within the html but I am linking the image through css. At least it seems to still not be working for me. When I add the position absolute my image disappears.

Comment: @RyanKelly The picture in the third div seems to be scaling fine. I can't even see your .css when I try to inspect your code.